# nested rails partial doesn't draw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I have a table in a partial `_measures_findings_list.html.erb` where I want to replace the table row with another partial, which I can reuse elsewhere. `MeasuresFinding` is a model, so I first created a partial `_measures_finding.html.erb`, and tried:

```
<% render @measures_findings %>
```

then I tried

```
<% @measures_findings.each do |measures_finding| %>
  <% render 'measures_finding', measures_finding: measures_finding %>  
<% end %>
```

Nothing. Then

```
<% @measures_findings.each do |measures_finding| %>
  <% render 'measures_finding/measures_finding', measures_finding: measures_finding %>  
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong? Putting the code of the partial into the each loop works of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss '=', it should be

```
<%= render @measures_findings %>
```

Comment: Thanks to both answers. That happens when you stare for too long at a piece of code: you'll miss the obvious. All hail stackoverflow, ghe next best thing to pair programming!